# CSS canvas circle smoothness

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

I have a circle drawn in canvas, one of top of the other, the problem is that you can see the back one through the front one (red outline). Is there a way to improve this?

The only thing I can think of is the increase the size of the top one (lineWidth by pixel or 2) to completely cover the back one.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var canvas2 = document.getElementById('myCanvas2');
var context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = 70;

for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);

  context.lineWidth = 25;
  context.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
  context.stroke();
}

for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

  context2.beginPath();
  context2.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2.5, false);

  context2.lineWidth = 25;
  context2.strokeStyle = '#fff';
  context2.stroke();
}
```

```css
#myCanvas,
#myCanvas2{
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0zs2gqxk/3/

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is due to what is called *anti-aliasing* effect that is a direct result of the rendering in the browser.

As a *fix* you can specify the *start angle* for the *red arc* so that the issue do not occur - see demo below (a `background` has been added to `body` for illustration):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var canvas2 = document.getElementById('myCanvas2');
var context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = 70;

for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 2.5, 2 * Math.PI, false); /* CHANGED HERE*/

  context.lineWidth = 25;
  context.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
  context.stroke();
}

for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {

  context2.beginPath();
  context2.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2.5, false);

  context2.lineWidth = 25;
  context2.strokeStyle = '#fff';
  context2.stroke();
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #ddd;
}
#myCanvas,
#myCanvas2 {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: I dont understand how does start angle change this behavior?

Comment: @Toniq We won't be drawing the white arc over the red one, and yet completing the circle...

Comment: Aha.. ok thanks. This doesnt help me actually because I am using this as preloader (so I will be having both circles going around.)

Comment: @Toniq okay, so you mean to do something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/m64rse2v/1/